# What can cause gulp-typescript to generate different output each time

Tags: typescript, gulp, typescript1.8

We are using gulp-typescript on our build server and all of a sudden the generated javascript would not work sometimes. We have traced it to the fact that the generated javascript is in arbitrary order in the generated file.

I get the impression that using outFile is bad https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html and it may be time to get a proper module system. It just seems strange that it fails all of a sudden.

Which module system is to prefer if that is the solution?

gulpfile.js looks something like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsLint = require('gulp-tslint');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {}, ts.reporter.longReporter());

var config = {
    maps: './maps',
    scripts: './content/scripts'
};

gulp.task('tslint', function() {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsLint({
            configuration: {
                rules: { "semicolon": true }
            }
        }))
        .pipe(tsLint.report('verbose'));
});

gulp.task('typescript',['tslint'], function() {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(config.maps))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scripts));
    return tsResult;    

});
```

and tsconfig.json look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outFile": "application.js"
  },
  "files": [
      "list of all the files"       
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of outfile is indeed discouraged. Basarat explains on the page you linked

> If your code depends on any form of js ordering you will get random errors at runtime.

On to the second part of your question.

---

Ultimately what module system you want to use is mostly a matter of opinion.

Because...

- Most bundlers can handle quite a few different module types
- To simulate your current workflow you'll be feeding your modules directly into your bundler, so you'll never really be looking at them anyway.
- The typescript compiler will handle outputting any of them relatively easily
- It'll look the same as you write the actual typescript code

Subjectively, CommonJS seems to be one of the most popular (partly I suppose because it's got a history, partly because it's the default when you auto-generate a tsconfig.json. AMD also makes the rounds, require was a popular module loader for some time and was particularly interesting to folks that wanted to do dynamic loading of JS assets. SystemJS is the new hotness right now in the JS community and it does have its own module spec as well but it can load all of the others so I'm unaware of a compelling reason to use the system format over the alternatives.

Until you start to care about dynamic loading, just pick whichever one is the most aesthetically pleasing or has the coolest name.